# Application information missing in Spinnaker after re-adding GKE accounts - using spinnaker-for-gke

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spinnaker

I am using a Spinnaker implementation set up on GCP using the [spinnaker-for-gcp](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spinnaker-for-gcp) tools.  My initial setup worked fine.  However, we recently had to re-configure our GKE clusters (independently of Spinnaker).  Consequently I deleted and re-added our gke-accounts.  After doing that the Spinnaker UI appears to show the existing GKE-based applications but if I click on any of them there are no clusters or load balancers listed anymore!  Here are the [spinnaker-for-gcp](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spinnaker-for-gcp) commands that I executed:

```
$ hal config provider kubernetes account delete company-prod-acct
$ hal config provider kubernetes account delete company-dev-acct
$ ./add_gke_account.sh # for gke_company_us-central1_company-prod
$ ./add_gke_account.sh # for gke_company_us-west1-a_company-dev
$ ./push_and_apply.sh
```

When the above didn't work I did an experiment where I deleted the two account and added an account with a different name (but the same GKE cluster) and ran `push_and_apply`.  As before, the output messages seem to indicate that everything worked, but the Spinnaker UI continued to show all the old account names, despite the fact that I deleted them and added new ones (which did not show up).  And, as before, not details could be seen for any of the applications.  Also note that `hal config provider kubernetes account list` **did** show the new account name and **did not** show the old ones.

Any ideas for what I can do, other than complete recreating our Spinnaker installation?  Is there anything in particular that I should look for in the Spinnaker logs in GCP to provide more information?

Thanks in advance.

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the data that was in my `.kube/config` file in Cloud Shell was obsolete.  Removing that file,  recreating it (via the appropriate `kubectl` commands) and then running the commands mentioned in my original description fixed the problem.

**Note,** though, that it took a lot of shell script and GCP log reading by our team to figure out the problem.  Ultimately, what would have been nice would have been if the `add_gke_account.sh or push_and_apply.sh`  scripts could have detected the issue, presumably by verifying that the expected changes did, in fact, correctly occur in the running spinnaker.